# "Order cannot be fulfilled" error after updating order status in Amazon MWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

Hello I have listed all the order available in my orders by using Orders API, 
Now i wanted to update the order status as **Shipped** by using the Feed API,In **amazon Scratchpad** I used Feed API to Update the status of the Product and it is successfully submitted and then by using Feed-ID i checked the status of the submitted feed there is no Error in the status but except there is a Warning called this.

> Order cannot be fulfilled. For more information, please contact Seller Support

And the order status is not changing as Shipped.

This is the Feed I'm using to update the status And the feed type is _POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_
And I dont know what should i give under   so i just gave a random number, and i tried without this MerchantFulfillmentID but no use, Please Help me to solve this, Thanks

```
<?php
/** 
 *  PHP Version 5
 *
 *  @category    Amazon
 *  @package     MarketplaceWebService
 *  @copyright   Copyright 2009 Amazon Technologies, Inc.
 *  @link        http://aws.amazon.com
 *  @license     http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0  Apache License, Version 2.0
 *  @version     2009-01-01
 */

/**
 * Submit Feed  Sample
 */

include_once ('.config.inc.php'); 


// India
$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.in";

$config = array (
  'ServiceURL' => $serviceUrl,
  'ProxyHost' => null,
  'ProxyPort' => -1,
  'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
);


 $service = new MarketplaceWebService_Client(
     AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
     AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 
     $config,
     APPLICATION_NAME,
     APPLICATION_VERSION);


$ship_date = date("c");

$feed = <<<EOD
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
 <MerchantIdentifier>***********</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OrderFulfillment>
            <AmazonOrderID>111-1111111-1111111</AmazonOrderID>
            <FulfillmentDate>$ship_date</FulfillmentDate>
            <FulfillmentData>
                <CarrierName>Contact Us for Details</CarrierName>
                <ShippingMethod>Standard</ShippingMethod>
            </FulfillmentData>
            <Item>
                <AmazonOrderItemCode>70359459457611</AmazonOrderItemCode>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            </Item>
        </OrderFulfillment>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
EOD;


// Constructing the MarketplaceId array which will be passed in as the the MarketplaceIdList 
// parameter to the SubmitFeedRequest object.
$marketplaceIdArray = array("Id" => array('************'));

 // MWS request objects can be constructed two ways: either passing an array containing the 
 // required request parameters into the request constructor, or by individually setting the request
 // parameters via setter methods.
 // Uncomment one of the methods below.

/********* Begin Comment Block *********/

$feedHandle = @fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');
fwrite($feedHandle, $feed);
rewind($feedHandle);
$parameters = array (
  'Merchant' => MERCHANT_ID,
  'MarketplaceIdList' => $marketplaceIdArray,
  'FeedType' => '_POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_',
  'FeedContent' => $feedHandle,
  'PurgeAndReplace' => false,
  'ContentMd5' => base64_encode(md5(stream_get_contents($feedHandle), true)),
  'MWSAuthToken' => '<MWS Auth Token>', // Optional
);

rewind($feedHandle);

$request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_SubmitFeedRequest($parameters);
/********* End Comment Block *********/



invokeSubmitFeed($service, $request);

//@fclose($feedHandle);




  *   
  * @param MarketplaceWebService_Interface $service instance of MarketplaceWebService_Interface
  * @param mixed $request MarketplaceWebService_Model_SubmitFeed or array of parameters
  */
  function invokeSubmitFeed(MarketplaceWebService_Interface $service, $request) 
  {
      try {
              $response = $service->submitFeed($request);

                echo ("Service Response\n");
                echo ("=============================================================================\n");

                echo("        SubmitFeedResponse\n");
                if ($response->isSetSubmitFeedResult()) { 
                    echo("            SubmitFeedResult\n");
                    $submitFeedResult = $response->getSubmitFeedResult();
                    if ($submitFeedResult->isSetFeedSubmissionInfo()) { 
                        echo("                FeedSubmissionInfo\n");
                        $feedSubmissionInfo = $submitFeedResult->getFeedSubmissionInfo();
                        if ($feedSubmissionInfo->isSetFeedSubmissionId()) 
                        {
                            echo("                    FeedSubmissionId\n");
                            echo("                        " . $feedSubmissionInfo->getFeedSubmissionId() . "\n");
                        }
                        if ($feedSubmissionInfo->isSetFeedType()) 
                        {
                            echo("                    FeedType\n");
                            echo("                        " . $feedSubmissionInfo->getFeedType() . "\n");
                        }
                        if ($feedSubmissionInfo->isSetSubmittedDate()) 
                        {
                            echo("                    SubmittedDate\n");
                            echo("                        " . $feedSubmissionInfo->getSubmittedDate()->format(DATE_FORMAT) . "\n");
                        }
                        if ($feedSubmissionInfo->isSetFeedProcessingStatus()) 
                        {
                            echo("                    FeedProcessingStatus\n");
                            echo("                        " . $feedSubmissionInfo->getFeedProcessingStatus() . "\n");
                        }
                        if ($feedSubmissionInfo->isSetStartedProcessingDate()) 
                        {
                            echo("                    StartedProcessingDate\n");
                            echo("                        " . $feedSubmissionInfo->getStartedProcessingDate()->format(DATE_FORMAT) . "\n");
                        }
                        if ($feedSubmissionInfo->isSetCompletedProcessingDate()) 
                        {
                            echo("                    CompletedProcessingDate\n");
                            echo("                        " . $feedSubmissionInfo->getCompletedProcessingDate()->format(DATE_FORMAT) . "\n");
                        }
                    } 
                } 
                if ($response->isSetResponseMetadata()) { 
                    echo("            ResponseMetadata\n");
                    $responseMetadata = $response->getResponseMetadata();
                    if ($responseMetadata->isSetRequestId()) 
                    {
                        echo("                RequestId\n");
                        echo("                    " . $responseMetadata->getRequestId() . "\n");
                    }
                } 

                echo("            ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $response->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
     } catch (MarketplaceWebService_Exception $ex) {
         echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
         echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
         echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n");
         echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n");
         echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n");
         echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n");
         echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $ex->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
     }
 }
```

Edited the above code..This is what contains in my Submit feed API.

Comment: Is this for an actual real order that you are fulfilling? If yes, just contact seller support and they can help you faster then we can.

Comment: Yes is real order.

Comment: But the i want to mark this item as shipped from API, Not manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following code to ship orders using Feeds API.

```
$order_id = str_replace('"', "", $product_list[$i][0]);
$ship_date = date("c");
$carrier_code = str_replace('"', "", $product_list[$i][4]);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//THE FulfillmentDate MUST BE BETWEEN THE ORDER DATE AND NOW
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$pre_message .= "<Message>";
$pre_message .= "<MessageID>$i</MessageID>";
$pre_message .= "<OrderFulfillment>";
$pre_message .= "<AmazonOrderID>$order_id</AmazonOrderID>";
$pre_message .= "<FulfillmentDate>$ship_date</FulfillmentDate>";
$pre_message .= "<FulfillmentData>";
$pre_message .= "<CarrierCode>Royal Mail</CarrierCode>";
$pre_message .= "</FulfillmentData>";
$pre_message .= "</OrderFulfillment>";
$pre_message .= "</Message>";

$feed = <<<EOD
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>$merchant_token</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
$pre_message
</AmazonEnvelope>
EOD;

$feed = trim($feed);

$marketplaceIdArray = array("Id" => array($MARKETPLACE_ID));
$feedHandle = @fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');
fwrite($feedHandle, $feed);
rewind($feedHandle); //Sets file pointer at beginning of file

$parameters = array(
    'Merchant' => $MERCHANT_ID,
    'MarketplaceIdList' => $marketplaceIdArray,
    'FeedType' => '_POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_',
    'FeedContent' => $feedHandle,
    'PurgeAndReplace' => false, //Leave this PurgeAndReplace to false so that it want replace whole product in amazon inventory
    'ContentMd5' => base64_encode(md5(stream_get_contents($feedHandle), true))
);

rewind($feedHandle);
$request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_SubmitFeedRequest($parameters);

$return_feed = invokeSubmitFeed($service, $request);
```

Comment: Hii, thanks for the code, i tried giving the way you have given the XML in amazon scratchpad then also the same warning is coming..

Comment: Can you please post your whole code so that I can check if there is anything to change.

Comment: I have edited the and posted whole code at top, please look into it.

Comment: Hi Salman the only thing I can think of is, I don't know if you have declared DATE_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d'; in config file. and also you don't need  <Item><AmazonOrderItemCode></AmazonOrderItemCode><Quantity></Quantity></Item> if you are shipping everything in that order.

Comment: The date format is 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z' , is it correct?

Comment: Ok i will try again.