# Amazon Order Feed API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

We have use Order Feeds API for Amazon Order Processing API. We use `_POST_FLAT_FILE_FUILFILLMENT_DATA` feed type. But it gives the warning:

> Order cannot be fulfilled. For more information please contact seller support.

The flat file that we created are given below: ordered, orderitemid,  quantity, ship date, carriercode,  carriername,  tracking number and shipmethod.  Ordered and shipmate (yyyyy-mm-dd and dispatch date is inserted) and other fields is blank.

Where we are making a mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order Process of Amazon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207180/order-process-of-amazon)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of your prior question.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the flat file format to upload fulfillment data (I use the XML format), so my experiences may not apply to your case. But when I hit the "Order cannot be fulfilled" problem, it was a problem with the date format. The same seems to be true for this SO question: ["Order cannot be fulfilled" error after updating order status in Amazon MWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616948/order-cannot-be-fulfilled-error-after-updating-order-status-in-amazon-mws)

Comment: Please pass the date in yyyy-mm-dd.